Is there any standard procedure or guideline to solve complex asymmetrical trusses such as saw tooth type of truss used for polyhouse construction?
I want to solve for the dead load,live load as well as wind load for a saw tooth type of truss, which is asymmetrical in nature....generally used for the construction of greenhouse. I also want to further find forces in each member of the truss..is there a standard method for that?

So would the greenhouse manufacturers have done that? Any analysis shown in textbooks?

If the geometry is too general, you might want to use general method like FEA. Could you add a picture of the structure?

Yes there is, a Cremona diagram, preferably using Bow's notation.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cremona_diagram
https://wiki.dtonline.org/index.php/Bow%27s_Notation
